# Is there a way to check if a variable is a Date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, typechecking

I was wondering if there is any way to check if an object is specifically a Date in JavaScript. isType returns object for Date, which isn't enough for this scenario. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Use instanceof

```
(myvar instanceof Date) // returns true or false
```

Comment: It will work for *most cases*, but it will fail on multi-frame DOM environments, give a look to [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/).

Comment: I tested it with an "Invalid Date" and it returned true!!

Comment: This is not working as expected in my case where I've used DHTMLX Calendar type in date field.

Answer (score 45):

`Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Date]"` will work in every case, and `obj instanceof Date` will only work in date objects from the same view instance (`window`).

Comment: Hmm this won't work if you have something that inherits from Date, will it?

Comment: This is how Ext JS does it. Not sure about other frameworks, but that's what I would look at.

Comment: @Claudiu: No, but honestly, I think you'll never need to create an object instance that inherits from `Date.prototype`..., @bmoeskau, this is the safest way to detect the *kind* of an object made by the built-in constructors like `Array`, `RegExp`, `Date`, etc... other frameworks, like jQuery use this to [detect `Array` objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/object/isstring) also use it for this and to detect primitive values wrapped, since those wrappers are objects, e.g. `typeof new String("") == 'object';` and also for detecting Opera.

Comment: Well, if it inherits from Date, it is a Date object. This seems to be a really good answer!

Comment: Wouldn't testing against `d.constructor.name` better?

Answer (score -2):

if(obj && obj.getUTCDay){
// I'll treat it like a Date
}

Comment: If you happen to have a similar method called "getUTCDay" on a completely unrelated object this will return true for `obj` even if it isn't a Date.

Comment: Or more likely, if someone *after* you writes a getUTCDay method somewhere in your code base, they'll have a nice long afternoon of debugging at some point ;)

Answer (score -6):

```
if (parseDate("datestring"))
```

Comment: I assume you realize that this is not the same is checking for a Date object type, which seems to be the question?

Comment: oooh!! i misunderstood the question =/ my bad